# Is it safe to force shutdown a mac while booting?

Tags: high-sierra, shutdown

So I have the 2015 "13 MacBook so I read some articles to update firmware by holding the power button so i tried to try it for fun but I misunderstood the article and I held the power button while my mac had completed 1/4 of booting process. So I accidentally force shutdown my mac while it was booting. So should I worry about some firmware error or some sort of software error which I can't notice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any forced shutdown can leave a file in a bad state. At boot, you would only corrupt a system file, so that's usually easy to reinstall the OS so I suppose if you care about user data - that's the best time to force a stop.

High Sierra supports internet recovery and bootable install media, so the options to reinstall are much better than the old days where you needed a CD or DVD to reinstall and it took a long time.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response actually i don't care that much about a system file because maybe the system itself may rebuild it. And also I don't notice any type of problem in my mac!

Comment: But I believe no system file would have been corrupted because in the 1/4 boot process only the kexts are loaded.